# Failover and Failback SQL Server Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, high-availability, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

I had a question on Log shipping Manual Fail over

Let me explain about environment, Primary Server A (with Cluster setup A-P Mode) Secondary server B(DR server standalone).

We had enabled Log Shipping on a database TEST from Primary Server and now we would like to test by doing a manual fail over and i had few questions.

Log Shipping Jobs are disabled on both A and B Servers and Log shipping is not disabled or removed, Once the Server B is brought online by restoring the all the logs from Server A

- Can i re-attach/reconfigure the secondary database to existing Log shipping once it is online.
- I tried using backup with no recovery option on secondary database and log shipping restore jobs are skipping.
- Is there any method expect role changing can we reconfigure the log-shipping without restoring the database from first?

any references would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Related - see my answer at http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77429/8783

Comment: I know to do Failover and Failback is there any process if the secondary DB is online, Now i want to take a log backup with norecovery on secondary DB(now it changes to restoring mode) and try to reestablish the log shipping will this work? as i know it will skip the restoration process. Else only process is to build the complete Log Shipping from scratch.

Comment: Did you see my anwer linked above ? Its exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes  I had seen your article. You might not understood my question and I repeat i know to do Failover and Failback of Log shipping what you had discussed in case of Hurricane Sandy is correct.  1) I want to bring the Secondary database online and primary to online and i had  removed or not both case is applicable log shipping configuration.  2) Now secondary Db is online and i want to take it to restoring mode using norecovery and i want reinitialize Log shipping on the same DB from primary to secondary is it possible?  Is my question clear to you or can i repeat again no failback one failover

Comment: @kin 1) One Manual Failover from Primary to secondary and No Failback required, 2) Both primary and secondary are online no more failback, 3) No transaction committed on primary and secondary both are idle, 4) Can i take the secondary database to restoring mode and reinitialize log shipping will be possible in any methods?

Comment: What you are telling is not possuble as it breaks the log chain. The most you can do is to take a diff backup and restore with no recovery following tlog backups - provided a full backup is not done which will reset the diff bit.

Comment: Yes i know that log shipping will break, If i try to re-initialize ii am able to do, but logs shipped from primary to secondary are skipping while restoring on secondary database.  </br> Thanks for your Answer, If any possible way to do for large databases like this provide a link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disaster Recovery Options for Sql Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/disaster-recovery-options-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to reinitialize log shipping from B to A?

If yes, then once you bring the DR site database (B) online you automatically break the LSN chain hence the restore log files will be skipped. The only way to reestablish log shipping is to remove log shipping setup completely, create backup of database B, restore at database A in stand by/readonly and then setup log shipping from B.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to reinitialize log shipping from B to A? **No**

I know to do Failover and Failback in Logshipping(A -> B and B -> A), I want the Server B to be online and check it is online (ensure Failover is done) Now i want again Server B to be reinitialized for Log shipping(A -> B only) process without reestablish of Log shipping from Server A to Server B from scratch as it's a large sized database.